# How to clear search history in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search, history

I am using Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2. The search bar in both Search and Find/Replace is getting cluttered from previous searches. Is there a way to clear them?

I tried clearing the cache files in `$workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/` but it does not help.

EDIT:
To clear File Search history, go to `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.search\dialog_settings.xml` and under the TextSearchPage section, clear the history sections (e.g. `<section name="HISTORY0">` ) and change HISTORY_SIZE value to 0.

To clear Java Search history, go to `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml` and do the same thing under the JavaSearchPage section.

To clear Remote Search history, go to `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.rse.ui\dialog_settings.xml` and do the same thing under the RemoteSearchPage section.

Still do not know how to clear the Find/Replace history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please open file .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.search\dialog_settings.xml in your workspce.

Search seaction `TextSearchPage`. 
Clear section history.
In this tag, be careful of `HISTORY_SIZE` and section `History`

I mean if `<item value="2" key="HISTORY_SIZE"/>`
`<section name="HISTORY0">` and `<section name="HISTORY1">` works.

Start eclipse.

For Find/Replace

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor\dialog_settings.xml
```

search for `findhistory`. You will see findHistory and replaceHistory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This clears the File search history. I also found that clearing the history in RemoteSearchPage section in org.eclipse.rse.ui\dialog_settings.xml clears the Remote Search history, and the JavaSearchPage section in org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml clears the Java Search history. However, I still could not find a way to clear the Find/Replace history.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete your .metadata file and it works all of your history is gone!

Comment: And a lot else besides ;-)

Comment: This is not only clearing the history but also many other plugins configurations.

Comment: you just have to delete this file `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor\dialog_settings.xml` or you can edit the history inside it. (make sure to close eclipse first)